# Displaying records from database on webpage

Tags: php, mysql

I'm attempting to display my data in a table from my database, I used the exact same code for another table but for some reason the table appears but is empty.

Thanks its solved!

Comment: Well, for one, you should include `workshopId` in your query's SELECT part. Secondly, execute the query manually and see if you get any results.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Have you tried running the SQL query manually in phpmyadmin to make sure you are getting results?

Comment: Your <a> tag is wrong. You forgot to open up and close the quotes on the href, and you forgot to close the tab with a `/`. Try fixing those.

Comment: what kind of error you getting

Comment: Sorry for the daft question but how would I run it manually? I'm quite new to PHP and attempting to teach myself throughout this project Also I added workshopId in the SELECT part and it still didnt work

Comment: run it on your mysql server, instead of using php

Comment: I dont see an open and close bracket on your while loop...

Comment: No error, just no data is displayed

Comment: Thank you everyone! Sorry for the daft questions it was because there was no brackets around my while loop

Answer (score 0):

you have to put brackets in while loop, close tag  and the last :

```
echo "<table border=1 cellpadding=5>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Workshop Name</th>";
echo "<th>Workshop Price (£)</th>";
echo "<th>Workshop Description</th>";
echo "<th>Further Information</th>";

echo "</tr>";

$SQL="select workshopId,workshopName, workshopPrice,workshopDescription from Workshops order by workshopId";
    $exeSQL=mysql_query($SQL) or die (mysql_error());
while ($arrayworkshop=mysql_fetch_array($exeSQL))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    //display details
    echo "<td>".$arrayworkshop['workshopName']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$arrayworkshop['workshopPrice']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$arrayworkshop['workshopDescription']."</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='ViewWorkshop.php?workshopId=".$arrayworkshop['workshopId']."'>";
    //Display name of the Task
    echo "Further Information"."</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>"; 
}  
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry for the ridiculously daft questions!